# Advice on using unless requisite in a salt state file

Tags: bash, salt-stack, nghttp2

As part of a salt state file I am installing nghttp2.

So far I have the following code in my .sls

```
install_nghttp2:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        cd /tmp
        wget https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2/releases/download/v1.16.0/nghttp2-1.16.0.tar.gz
        tar -xf nghttp2-1.16.0.tar.gz
        cd ./nghttp2-1.16.0
        ./configure
        make
        make install
    - shell: /bin/bash
    - require:
      - pkg: install_nghttp2_deps
    - unless: test -x /tmp/nghttp2-1.16.0
```

I'm a little wary of the `- unless` requisite and was wondering if anyone had a better way to check nghttp2 hasn't already been installed? I'd rather do something to check it hasn't been installed rather than just check whether it's been downloaded - unless (pun intended...kinda) anyone has a better suggestion?

Comment: When installed, will the path of `nghttp2-1.16.0` be appended in `$PATH` environment variable (or) any change you adding it yourself?

Comment: This is what package managers (`rpm`, `apt`, etc) are for. Build a package for `nghttp2` and install it via the package manager of your choice; then your `unless` test simply checks if the appropriate package is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you compile specific version and you do not install it with package manager, I think you are doing it right.

Maybe better option to check if the program is installed would be to use different command in *unless* requisite.

For example you can use `nghttpd --version` or with full path, where the binary is stored `/usr/sbin/nghttpd --version`.

Other good option is to use `which nghttpd`.